# make zpool status output scriptable

Tags: bash, freebsd, zfs

How can I turn the output of **zpool status -v** into something usable, with data that match by row in a data.oriented format, instead of the silly "visual" output it uses, so that it's something *scriptable*, using standard unix-like utilities? I had a python script that did something acceptable, but python 3 completely breaks it, and I'm not fixing it just to have some new version of python break it again. (after screwing around getting the script to run with no errors, it returns nothing  :)

bascially this space-bar alinged mess:

```
              pool: data
             state: ONLINE
            status: Some supported features are not enabled on the pool. The pool can
                    still be used, but some features are unavailable.
            action: Enable all features using 'zpool upgrade'. Once this is done,
                    the pool may no longer be accessible by software that does not support
                    the features. See zpool-features(7) for details.
              scan: scrub repaired 0 in 4h52m with 0 errors on Fri Aug 18 04:52:47 2017
            config:

                    NAME                                            STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
                    data                                            ONLINE       0     0     0
                      mirror-0                                      ONLINE       0     0     0
                        gptid/6dfb7dbe-68c5-11e6-982d-00e04c68f511  ONLINE       0     0     0
                        gptid/27f40ebe-8f1b-11e4-94f8-3085a9405b85  ONLINE       0     0     0
                        gptid/9244318f-c1b4-11e6-a31d-0cc47ae2abe8  ONLINE       0     0     0
                      mirror-1                                      ONLINE       0     0     0
                        gptid/1993f2d7-8f1b-11e4-94f8-3085a9405b85  ONLINE       0     0     0
                        gptid/529e2c88-f1d1-11e6-89c3-0cc47ae2abe8  ONLINE       0     0     0
                        gptid/53a09a3e-f1d1-11e6-89c3-0cc47ae2abe8  ONLINE       0     0     0
                      mirror-2                                      ONLINE       0     0     0
                        gptid/51f3b377-6a20-11e6-be8c-00e04c68f511  ONLINE       0     0     0
                        gptid/9fb54bde-1e2d-11e7-a83e-0cc47ae2abe8  ONLINE       0     0     0
                        gptid/9eebde32-1e2d-11e7-a83e-0cc47ae2abe8  ONLINE       0     0     0
                    cache
                      gptid/63db5172-20bd-11e7-b561-0cc47ae2abe8    ONLINE       0     0     0

            errors: No known data errors
```

to something with actual *columnns* like this:

```
            NAME                                                            STATE   READ    WRITE   CKSUM
            data                                                            ONLINE  0       0       0
            data    mirror-0                                                ONLINE  0       0       0
            data    mirror-0    gptid/6dfb7dbe-68c5-11e6-982d-00e04c68f511  ONLINE  0       0       0
            data    mirror-0    gptid/27f40ebe-8f1b-11e4-94f8-3085a9405b85  ONLINE  0       0       0
            data    mirror-0    gptid/9244318f-c1b4-11e6-a31d-0cc47ae2abe8  ONLINE  0       0       0
            data    mirror-1                                                ONLINE  0       0       0
            data    mirror-1    gptid/1993f2d7-8f1b-11e4-94f8-3085a9405b85  ONLINE  0       0       0
            data    mirror-1    gptid/529e2c88-f1d1-11e6-89c3-0cc47ae2abe8  ONLINE  0       0       0
            data    mirror-1    gptid/53a09a3e-f1d1-11e6-89c3-0cc47ae2abe8  ONLINE  0       0       0
            data    mirror-2                                                ONLINE  0       0       0
            data    mirror-2    gptid/51f3b377-6a20-11e6-be8c-00e04c68f511  ONLINE  0       0       0
            data    mirror-2    gptid/9fb54bde-1e2d-11e7-a83e-0cc47ae2abe8  ONLINE  0       0       0
            data    mirror-2    gptid/9eebde32-1e2d-11e7-a83e-0cc47ae2abe8  ONLINE  0       0       0
            data    cache
            data    cache       gptid/63db5172-20bd-11e7-b561-0cc47ae2abe8  ONLINE  0   0   0
```

I can use perl to remove and rearrange, but I can't work out how to match the rows dynamically, in a way that would work with mirror/raidz123/stripe/cache.

```
            datadata                                            ONLINE       0     0     0
            data  mirror-0                                      ONLINE       0     0     0
            data    gptid/6dfb7dbe-68c5-11e6-982d-00e04c68f511  ONLINE       0     0     0
            data    gptid/27f40ebe-8f1b-11e4-94f8-3085a9405b85  ONLINE       0     0     0
            data    gptid/9244318f-c1b4-11e6-a31d-0cc47ae2abe8  ONLINE       0     0     0
            data  mirror-1                                      ONLINE       0     0     0
            data    gptid/1993f2d7-8f1b-11e4-94f8-3085a9405b85  ONLINE       0     0     0
            data    gptid/529e2c88-f1d1-11e6-89c3-0cc47ae2abe8  ONLINE       0     0     0
            data    gptid/53a09a3e-f1d1-11e6-89c3-0cc47ae2abe8  ONLINE       0     0     0
            data  mirror-2                                      ONLINE       0     0     0
            data    gptid/51f3b377-6a20-11e6-be8c-00e04c68f511  ONLINE       0     0     0
            data    gptid/9fb54bde-1e2d-11e7-a83e-0cc47ae2abe8  ONLINE       0     0     0
            data    gptid/9eebde32-1e2d-11e7-a83e-0cc47ae2abe8  ONLINE       0     0     0
            datacache
            data  gptid/63db5172-20bd-11e7-b561-0cc47ae2abe8    ONLINE       0     0     0
```

This is the code that generates the above.

```
            zpool status -v data | sed '/   data/, $!d' | grep -v errors: > /tmp/diskslistzpoolstatusdata
            perl -pi -e 's/^\n$//' /tmp/diskslistzpoolstatusdata  #remove blank lines
            perl -pi -e 's/\t$//' /tmp/diskslistzpoolstatusdata
            perl -p -i -e 's/\t//g' /tmp/diskslistzpoolstatusdata
            perl -pi -e 's/^/data/' /tmp/diskslistzpoolstatusdata
```

extra:

include the scrub summary and error lines per gptid

```
            NAME                                                            STATE   READ    WRITE   CKSUM
            misc                                                            ONLINE  0       0       0
            misc    mirror-0                                                ONLINE  0       0       0
            misc    mirror-0    gptid/aefbaf6e-e004-11e6-8f42-0cc47ae2abe8  ONLINE  0       0       0       0err/4h52m/0err/Fri Aug 18 04:52:47 2017    No known data errors
            misc    mirror-0    gptid/affc3cac-e004-11e6-8f42-0cc47ae2abe8  ONLINE  0       0       0       0err/4h52m/0err/Fri Aug 18 04:52:47 2017    No known data errors
            misc    cache       gptid/3139819b-20bd-11e7-b561-0cc47ae2abe8  ONLINE  0       0       0       0err/4h52m/0err/Fri Aug 18 04:52:47 2017    No known data errors
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no integrated solution available. You have two options:

1. **Parse it yourself in a language of your choice.** You already extracted the essential information. The layout is relatively static, as vdevs and pools cannot be nested (pools contain vdevs, never pools themselves), the order is respected (no devices from vdev A come after vdev B), the keywords are few and fixed (mirror-N, raidzX-N, etc), and the output is quite small (less than hundreds of lines usually). This means you just have to go through each row, read the info you need, store it in nested objects or simply arrays and go to the next line.
2. **Directly call the appropriate C functions to get the status in non-readable form and convert the output.** To do this, have a look at [status_callback(zpool_handle_t *zhp, void *data)](https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/blob/8f9a8cb713c7aacb6b1ec423716315b430386f88/usr/src/cmd/zpool/zpool_main.c#L4175), where all `printf`-output is generated from the pool data. You could mirror this function to convert the output into a format you like instead of the indented format, and then call your mini-application from your script to give you your data.

If you are familiar with C, option 2 would be faster I think. Performance-wise it does not matter much, as the data is small (even on big systems) and the calls will most likely be very infrequent (as pool layouts do not change often).

Comment: hmm. 
2 is interesting but my c, which was fairly limited to start with, is very rusty.
I was mostly hoping that someone might have some insight into how I might do #1, as loops make me loopy :|. 
I dont grasp the string regex stuff at all, the whole thing just looks like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck
all of the perl there is pretty much from google, with the obvious text string changed. its very...rough since its so alien to me.